# C++ getopt long for windows

Tags: c++, getopt

Hi i'm trying to find `getopt_long` for Windows. I found the regular `getopt` but no version for `getopt_long`. Somebody who here who might know?

Comment: GNU getopt for Visual Studio: https://github.com/skandhurkat/Getopt-for-Visual-Studio

Comment: You can try to look at [Boost.Program_options](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/program_options.html) ?

Comment: Another one would be cargs: https://github.com/likle/cargs